# JavaFX changing buttons' color based off input

Tags: javafx, user-input, scenebuilder

I'm currently using javaFX to build a visualization tool. You can see in the image below there are textboxes and green buttons. For every textbox with a 0 shown, it is linked to a specific button beneath it. However, the button is only supposed to turn green if the input value is 1. In case of input 0, the button is supposed to be white; and in case of any other number, an error message is supposed to pop up.

scene builder preview

[image: scene builder]

I tried to make a class in Controller.java that would intake the fx:id from scenebuilder but that didn't work. I'm trying to find a way where I am able to use specific names for each textbox because each one is linked to a different button.

Comment: *"I tried to make a class in Controller.java that would intake the fx:id from scenebuilder but that didn't work"* -> for these kinds of questions, you should provide the code you tried (a [mcve]).  FXML is built to link objects to controller fields via fx:id references, so the approach is correct (well, at least that part of it).  Therefore your implementation must be wrong.  But what is wrong with the implementation cannot be determined if you don't provide the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is create a `ChangeListener` to handle all the logic. The other is you can create a different `ChangeListener` for each `TextField`.

Example of `ChangeListener` for all `TextFields`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class App extends Application {
    Map<TextField, Button> nodeMap = new HashMap();    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){     
       
        TextField tfOne = new TextField();
        TextField tfTwo = new TextField();
        Button btnOne = new Button("One");
        btnOne.getStyleClass().add("left-arrow");
        Button btnTwo = new Button("Two");
        btnTwo.getStyleClass().add("right-arrow");
    
        nodeMap.put(tfOne, btnOne);
        nodeMap.put(tfTwo, btnTwo);
        
        VBox root = new VBox();
        
        HBox topRoot = new HBox(tfOne, tfTwo);
        topRoot.setSpacing(3);
        
        HBox bottomRoot = new HBox(btnOne, btnTwo);
        bottomRoot.setSpacing(3);        
        
        tfOne.textProperty().addListener(textFieldChangeListener);
        tfTwo.textProperty().addListener(textFieldChangeListener);
        
        root.getChildren().addAll(topRoot, bottomRoot);
        Scene newScene = new Scene(root);
        newScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("button_shape.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setWidth(200);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.setScene(newScene);
        stage.show();
    }

    ChangeListener<String> textFieldChangeListener =    (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                                                            String id;
                                                            
                                                            switch (newValue) {
                                                                case "":
                                                                    id = "";
                                                                    break;
                                                                case "0":
                                                                    id = "button-color-white";
                                                                    break;
                                                                case "1":
                                                                    id = "button-color-green";
                                                                    break;
                                                                default:
                                                                    id = "button-color-red";
                                                            }
                                                            
                                                            TextField key = ((TextField)((StringProperty)observable).getBean());
                                                            nodeMap.get(key).setId(id);                                                            
                                                        };
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

### CSS

```
.button{
    -fx-font-size: 16pt;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 10, 0, 0, 0);
}
.right-arrow{
    -fx-shape: "M 224 210 Q 280 210 294 210 Q 294 168 294 168 Q 350 238 350 238 C 350 238 350 224 294 294 C 294 252 294 252 294 252 L 224 252 Z";    
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.left-arrow{
    -fx-shape: "M 420 210 Q 322 210 322 210 Q 322 210 322 168 Q 280 238 280 238 L 322 294 C 322 252 322 252 322 252 L 420 252 Z";    
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.up-arrow{
    -fx-shape: "M 322 378 Q 322 294 322 294 Q 322 294 364 294 Q 294 224 294 224 L 224 294 C 266 294 266 294 266 294 L 266 378 Z";
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.down-arrow{
    -fx-shape: "M 322 294 Q 322 378 322 378 Q 322 378 364 378 Q 294 434 294 434 L 224 378 C 266 378 266 378 266 378 L 266 294 Z";
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.rectangle{
    -fx-shape: "M 322 294 Q 322 350 322 350 C 210 350 210 350 210 350 L 210 294 Z";
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

#button-color-green{
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

#button-color-red{
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

#button-color-white{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

### Output

[image]

### Edit after feedback

CSS is not a strong point of mine. This can probably be improved.

1. Set the stylesheet on the stage.
2. Set the node's `.getStyleClass()`
3. Use the node's `setId` to alter its style.

Comment: You're solving the problem by creating new text boxes and new buttons. That's not needed as there already specific buttons and text fields that already exist. The question is how do I connect each of these unique textboxes to their designated button from scenebuilder. For example, RT1LFTinTransitRevInput in the textbox should change the output button RT1LFTinTransitRevsideOutput.

Comment: You don't create anything from `SceneBuilder`. What is going on is nodes are created in `FXML`. From there, you have to use `@FXML` to get access to the node. The code should not have to be exact. This should be basic knowledge. The pure code ideas should be simple enough to use when nodes are created via `FXML`. If a person can't use these ideas interchangeably, then IMO, they need to spend more time learning the basics. So the big difference that is being cried about here is `Node node = new Node();` vs `@FXML Node node;` @user23122208

Comment: look at the edit I just made and see if you can work around it please @SedJ601

Comment: I don’t understand your issue from the edit. Here is what should be going on in your controller. Something like: 
`@FXML TextField textfieldFxIdOne, textfieldFxIdTwo, etc;
@FXML Button buttonFxIdOne, buttonFxIdTwo, etc;
Map<TextField, Button> nodeMap = new HashMap();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, Resources resources){
 nodeMap.put(textfieldFxIdOne, buttonFxIdOne);
 nodeMap.put(textfieldFxIdTwo, buttonFxIdTwo);
 etc; 
 textfieldFxIdOne.textProperty.addListener(textFieldChangeListener);
 textfieldFxIdTwo.textProperty.addListener(textFieldChangeListener);
 etc;
}`

Comment: When you said edit, I thought you were talking about you edited your question. I now see that you edited my answer.

Comment: I think that if you set your stylesheet in  `FXML`, then you only have to set the `IDs` to get the behavior you want. I am not 100% sure about that because I don't use `CSS` much.